# Load average and processor count

Tags: cpu-usage, cpu-cores, cpu-load

If I have a CPU with 8 cores, is it okay to have a consistent average load of 2.5? Or should it always remain below 1, irrespective of the number of processors / cores?

Comment: 2.5 what exactly?

Comment: Load average from the output of `uptime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me cite from my training's documentation. This will answer your question.

> The load average is displayed using three different sets of numbers,
>   as shown in the following example:
>
> The last piece of information is the average load of the system.
>   Assuming our system is a single-CPU system, the 0.25 means that for
>   the past minute, on average, the system has been 25% utilized. 0.12 in
>   the next position means that over the past 5 minutes, on average, the
>   system has been 12% utilized; and 0.15 in the final position means
>   that over the past 15 minutes, on average, the system has been 15%
>   utilized. If we saw a value of 1.00 in the second position, that would
>   imply that the single-CPU system was 100% utilized, on average, over
>   the past 5 minutes; this is good if we want to fully use a system. A
>   value over 1.00 for a single-CPU system implies that the system was
>   over-utilized: there were more processes needing CPU than CPU was
>   available.
>
> If we had more than one CPU, say a quad-CPU system, we would divide
>   the load average numbers by the number of CPUs. In this case, for
>   example, seeing a 1 minute load average of 4.00 implies that the
>   system as a whole was 100% (4.00/4) utilized during the last minute.
>
> Short term increases are usually not a problem. A high peak you see is
>   likely a burst of activity, not a new level. For example, at start up,
>   many processes start and then activity settles down. If a high peak is
>   seen in the 5 and 15 minute load averages, it would may be cause for
>   concern.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is no specific load average that is okay or not okay, and because the load average measures I/O as well as CPU usage, the number of cores is basically irrelevant. If the system is performing acceptably, then it's acceptable. If not, not.